# Colored var_dump with Xdebug not working properly

Tags: php, xdebug, var-dump

I recently upgraded PHP to 7.2. I lost the colored var_dump. So, I read this post :

[How to get xdebug var_dump to show full object/array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9998490/how-to-get-xdebug-var-dump-to-show-full-object-array)

and install xdebug by following these instructions:

http://www.dieuwe.com/blog/xdebug-ubuntu-1604-php7

and add this line to my php.ini:

```
xdebug.overload_var_dump=2
```

according to

[Colored var_dump() and errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31771836/colored-var-dump-and-errors)

And there is still no color in var_dump. I wonder why it's not working ?

**My Linux version:**  4.9.120-c9 #1 SMP Wed Aug 15 22:48:26 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

**My PHP version:** PHP Version 7.2.9-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is on the [Xdebug FAQ](https://xdebug.org/docs/faq):

> ***Q: Xdebug doesn't format output.***
>
> *A: Make sure you have PHP's html_errors set to 1 in php.ini*

Add or update the `html_errors` line in your php.ini:

```
html_errors = On
```